# Capture image from Honeywell Imaging Scanner

Tags: c#, pos-for-.net, honeywell

I am using a Honeywell Xenon Imaging scanner to capture both images and barcode. I have the barcodes working but am stuck trying to read an image. Using Microsoft.PointOfService, I am unable to cast the scanner as a ImageScanner, so instead am trying to send a DirectIO command to retrieve an image off the device. Using the honeywell EZConfig I can capture an image by sending the command `IMGSNP0T;IMGSHP6F2P` - however I can't figure out how to do this with Microsoft POS.

This is what I have now:

```
            string command = "IMGSNP0T;IMGSHP6F2P";
            DirectIOData response = scanner.DirectIO(0, 1024, command);
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])response.Object;
            Console.WriteLine("$: Response: " + BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
```

Which gives me this error:

```
[PosException]: Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: Method DirectIO threw an exception.  Attempt was made to perform an illegal or unsupported operation with the device, or an invalid parameter value was used.
ErrorCode: Failure
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
```

I believe the error could be with one of the first two params of the DirectIO command, I am not sure what I am meant to pass in for them and was just guessing, here is the method:

```
public abstract DirectIOData DirectIO(int command, int data, object obj);
```

Comment: You won't be able to use that feature via the POS-for.NET API. This is because the POS-for.NET barcode scanner does not have an interface to receive image data.
If you want to receive image data, please operate the serial port directly from the application without using POS-for.NET. In that case, the application must also receive the barcode data directly.

Comment: For example, these materials are available and Xenon is not included. [Does the scanner support direct I/O with OPOS?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Does-the-scanner-support-direct-IO-with-OPOS), [How to send a command to the scanner using OPOS driver through DirectIO function?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-send-a-command-to-the-scanner-using-OPOS-driver-through-DirectIO-function), [UnifiedPOS (UPOS) Controls - Honeywell Scanning and Mobility](https://aidc.honeywell.com/CatalogDocuments/4600G%20USER_GUI/UNIFIED_.PDF)

Comment: @kunif Well I did manage to get the DirectIO command to be received by the device, when i sent the first param to 10, the device now gets the command and I can press the trigger to snap a picture, but then my application timeout while waiting for a response... Is that what you mean by it cant receive the image data? I was hoping using directIO I could get it to read the bytes of the image of the device

Comment: Perhaps Honeywell's OPOS does not expect to receive image data from the scanner. JavaPOS has a specification to notify by DirectIOEvent when some data is received from the scanner, but OPOS does not have a description to notify such. Why not ask your vendor or reseller if they have the ability to receive image data?